# Check if one year has passed since last entry in a csv file

Tags: r

I have a csv file with financial information, and aim to update it in a small R script. The second variable in the csv file is a date, which was saved with write.csv(). But when I import it with read.csv the same variable becomes a factor.

When I try:

```
  data<-read.csv("./finances.csv")
  lastentry<-tail(data)


  if ((as.Date(lastentry$date, format ="%Y/%m/%d")-Sys.Date())>365) {
      ....
  }
```

I get:

```
Error in if ((as.Date(lastentry$date, format = "%Y/%m/%d") - Sys.Date()) >  : 
  value absent where TRUE/FALSE is needed
```

- How can I check if the lastentry$date is more than 365 days old?

Comment: try read.csv("./finances.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Comment: I will try that, but note that the main problem is the subtraction. How to return true if dates differ more than 365 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over complicating things a bit, just try without the `if()`:

```
> x <- "2017/07/01"
> (as.Date(x, format ="%Y/%m/%d")-Sys.Date())>365
[1] FALSE
```